# How to connect TFS in Visual Studio code (2023)

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfs

Is there a licensed method (not necessarily supported) to connect to Teams Foundation Server in Visual Studio Code?

It appears there is native integration into visual studio and as late as 2018 there appears to be a method but the primary extension is no longer supported and was pulled from the store...

Edit:
It appears to have no impact on the git interface that the git repository is hosted in TFS. Once you clone the repository, VS Code source control works normally.

However, if you set the repository to TFVC you will not be able to integrate it without special tools since TFVC is not used in most orgs.

Comment: Currently there is no Microsoft support for TFVC in VSCode. You are correct that there was a VSCode extension from Microsoft that supported TFVC and it was pulled. You can access git repos hosted in TFS, but not TFVC repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no Microsoft support for TFVC in VSCode.

Git repos hosted in TFS (aka Azure DevOps) can be accessed, but not TFVC repos.

You are correct that there was a VSCode extension from Microsoft that supported TFVC and it was pulled.

On Windows if you have `tf.exe` (which is included with installs of Visual Studio), you can use `tf` from the terminal within VSCode.